# Where is the autogenerated password generated?

Tags: admin, customer-account

In the admin area, there is the "Send auto-generated password" checkbox in the customer area. Where is the corresponding function for that so I can modify it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi goto  `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/CustomerController.php` and then goto it `saveAction` function and then got `empty($data['account']['new_password'])` condition there magento check is `check box checked or no`t then generate password by generatePassword function

If you want to  auto generate password by

`generatePassword()` of object of class `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer_Model`

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer`

```
/**
 * Retrieve random password
 *
 * @param   int $length
 * @return  string
 */
public function generatePassword($length = 8)
{
    $chars = Mage_Core_Helper_Data::CHARS_PASSWORD_LOWERS
        . Mage_Core_Helper_Data::CHARS_PASSWORD_UPPERS
        . Mage_Core_Helper_Data::CHARS_PASSWORD_DIGITS
        . Mage_Core_Helper_Data::CHARS_PASSWORD_SPECIALS;
    return Mage::helper('core')->getRandomString($length, $chars);
}
```